# Spring SAML: back browser button cause Error validating SAML message

Tags: java, spring, saml, adfs

I'm using the project [spring-security-saml v.1.0.0.](http://repo.spring.io/list/release/org/springframework/security/extensions/spring-security-saml/1.0.0.RELEASE/)

From an external site that uses ADFS, the user authenticates and the external site redirects to my site  "myDomain.com/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SSO" ,
code  of the file "spring-security-saml2-sample.war" is then executed and in the file index.jsp (modified by me) after a series of checks it is accessed
to my site on the homepage.jsp.
In all the jsp pages I set the javascript to manage the back button of the browser, but only in one case it does not work:
when the user logs in with ADFS and lands on the homepage of my site, if he backs up with the browser and then logs in again with ADFS I get the page with Saml Errore, Message: **Error validating SAML message**

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter
```

Any idea?
thanks in advance :-)
bye

Comment: SAML messages have an id to prevent replay-attacks ,may be this is causing it. You may check OpenSAML debug logs (turn them on) and SAML request trace.

Comment: Hi, I found the correct Exception in log:    
"DEBUG SAMLAuthenticationProvider:98 - Error validating SAML message  
SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message xxxxx
ework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:139)"
This class is in file "/spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.0.jar", I manage the Exception in "error.jsp" 
if ( exception.getMessage().equals("Error validating SAML message") ... do a redirect :-)
Thanks again.

Comment: I also modify file "securityContext.xml" as reported in page https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/ in paragraph "Error 'InResponseToField doesn't correspond to sent message' during SSO" bye

Comment: about 'InResponseTo' ... either there is a bug on the IdP side as it has to send the ID of the SAML AuthnRequest as value of 'InResponseTo' in the SAML Response or the SP does not find it due to caching / multi-instance.

If front-channel binding is used, just look at the SAML request flow , e.g. using SAML tracer plugin for Firefox, and you will see which side makes the mistake.

Comment: We haven't access ADFS system, I install SAML Mozilla Plugin to view Request and Response, I don't understand where is error

Comment: If HTTP-POST binding is used to transmit the SAML Resposne from IdP to SP you don't need access to ADFS as the SAML Response will be transmitted via the user-agent (browser), so SAML tracer plugin is sufficient. You just need to compare the value of the 'ID' in the SAML AuthnRequest with the value of the 'InResponseTo' of the SAML response. They must be identically.